# Whats wrong if 'Invalid BS_jmpBoot in boot block: 000000'

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, startup, partition, guid

I have a corrupted partition and upon trying to repair it with `disk utility` it gives the error

```
Invalid BS_jmpBoot in boot block: 000000
```

Several postings on the [internet](https://steelpangolin.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/invalid-bs_jmpboot-in-boot-block-000000/) describe this problem related to a wrong partition type GUID. They mostly look at the problem from the perspective of having a NFS+ partition that eventually gets a wrong GUID.

My problem is different since this partition was/is a bootcamp partition.

```
$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/disk0
Password:
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
partition table automatically reloaded!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: hybrid
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with hybrid MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/disk0: 234441648 sectors, 111.8 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 55F62258-49D5-4E25-9580-AE6FCEB8D4B5
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 234441614
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 56299597 sectors (26.8 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          409640        98749479   46.9 GiB    AF00  BVMACPRO
   3        98749480       100019015   619.9 MiB   AB00  Recovery HD
   4       156317696       234440703   37.3 GiB    0700  BOOTCAMP
```